# Discord Random Image Bot spamming

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I prepared an sending random images discord bot. bot works smoothly but instead of just sending an image, it randomly sends all images in the folder. I need your help.(12 images available, prefix: !! ) codes;

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const settings = require('./settings.json');

var prefix = settings.prefix;

client.on('ready', () => {
console.log(`${client.user.tag} ready!`);
});

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'xgif' )
      number = 12;
      imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * (number -1 + 1)) + 1;
      msg.channel.send ( {files: ["./images/" + imageNumber + ".gif"]})
});

client.login(TOKEN HERE)
```

Comment: how does it randomly send all images? a random subset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have numerous problems leading to this.  First, your if statement isn't scoped properly.  Your code is the functional equivalent of:

```
if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'xgif' ) {
    number = 12;
}
imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * (number -1 + 1)) + 1;
msg.channel.send ( {files: ["./images/" + imageNumber + ".gif"]})
```

So what is happening is number is not always set to 12, and the last two lines execute with **every single message**, including messages that come from the bot itself.  You need to:
1. scope your if statement correctly.
2. ignore all bot message.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
    if(msg.author.bot) return; // Ignore bots!
    if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + 'xgif' ) {
        number = 12;
        imageNumber = Math.floor (Math.random() * (number -1 + 1)) + 1;
        msg.channel.send ( {files: ["./images/" + imageNumber + ".gif"]})
    } // End of if scope
}
```

Unlike Python, for one example, JavaScript and all other C-style syntax languages do not use white space to indicate scope.  An if statement with no brackets only includes the next single statement in it's scope.